# Преобразование std::vector<char> в char*

Tags: c++

```
std::vector <char> rawdata;

char *getData(){
    char dt[rawdata.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<=rawdata.size();i++){
        dt[i]=rawdata[i];
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Пытался сделать так, но функция ничего не возвращает

Comment: Надо было static перед char dt написать.

Comment: @AlexGlebe не будет ли при использовании такого способа утечек памяти?

Comment: Ваш код не компилируется
`vector_to_char_array.cpp:8:10: error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘dt’`. С++ не позволяет декларировать массивы переменного размера. С позволяет.

Answer (score 4):

Нельзя возвращать указатель на *локальный* массив - по выходу из функции его уже просто нет - кончилось его время жизни, и указатель указывает в никуда, приводя к *неопределенному поведению*.

Кроме того, стандарт не разрешает объявлять массив, размер которого не известен во время компиляции.

Раз у вас С++ - используйте `string`, например,

```
string getData()
{
    return string(rawdata.begin(),rawdata.end());
}
```

А вообще, многое зависит от того, что у вас в `rawdata` - С-строка, или просто массив символов...

P.S. А для ваших целей `rawdata.data()` не годится?

Comment: @AlexGlebe А неизвестно, что в исходном векторе.